# custom URL Scheme in iOS 6 not working?

Tags: ios, ios6

My app uses a custom URL scheme so i send a link to my users in an email which when clicked, launches my app installed on their devices. This was working seamlessly till iOS 6 came into picture.
Now when the users click on the link or even type the address manually in the safari they get an error saying "Safari cannot open the page because it is a local file."

Wondering if anyone else encountered the same or if someone has any pointers in this regard !!

Any help much appreciated...

**Update**: it works if I only give my app's custom url without any parameters.. e.g. if I do "reader-app://" it launches my app but if i do "reader-app://doc=xyz" it doesn't !

Comment: I'm seeing the same with a simple email link on an iOS 6 device.

Comment: seeing a similar issue with a custom NSURLProtocol for QLPreviewControllerDataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try: reader-app://?doc=xyz  (add a question mark after //) this way you'll specify a query string. It works for me, but it presents an alertdialog asking the user if she wants to open the url with my application

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `-` sign from `reader-app://`.

My URL was not working until I removed underscore sings from URL.

Ex:

`my_app://` is not working.

`myapp://` is working.

*That is just a guess.*